# Command line python script to generate image with n digits from MNIST data

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

A Python script to generate an image with a given number of digits from MNIST data on a single row.

Via arguments, the following can be specified (all optional, with defaults if necessary):

- width of resulting image(s)
- minimum margin between digits
- maximum margin between digits
- number of MNIST digits per image
- which characters to extract from MNIST
- number of images to generate
- which directory to save the images to

Possible application is to generate images to train an OCR system for digits, or some form of CAPTCHA.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import os
import pickle
import argparse

import numpy as np


def load_data_and_dict():
    """Checks if numpy format images and idx dict exist
    if so:
      load
    if not:
      prepare and load

    :return: tuple of:
      <numpy array> mnist images
      <numpy array> dictionary
    """

    # check if data and dicts exist else download and generate
    mnist_dir = './data'
    mnist_images_fn = "./mnist_images"
    mnist_images_fn_loc = os.path.join(mnist_dir, mnist_images_fn + ".npy")
    mnist_idx_dict_fn = "./mnist_idx_dict"
    mnist_idx_dict_fn_loc = os.path.join(mnist_dir, mnist_idx_dict_fn + ".pickle")
    if os.path.isfile(mnist_images_fn_loc) and os.path.isfile(mnist_idx_dict_fn_loc):
        print("Found image data, loading...", end="")
        images = np.load(mnist_images_fn_loc)
        with open(mnist_idx_dict_fn_loc, 'rb') as handle:
            idx_dict = pickle.load(handle)
        print("DONE")
    else:
        print("Not all image data found, preparing...")
        import gzip
        import shutil
        import urllib.request
        mnist_urls = ["http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz",
                      "http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz"]

        # download if not exists
        os.makedirs(mnist_dir, exist_ok=True)

        # Download the file if it does not exist
        for mnist_url in mnist_urls:
            download_filename = os.path.join(mnist_dir, os.path.basename(mnist_url))
            if not os.path.isfile(download_filename):
                print(f"Downloading: {mnist_url}")
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(mnist_url, download_filename)

        # extract zip files if necessary
        zip_files = [os.path.join(mnist_dir, x) for x in os.listdir(mnist_dir) if x.endswith('.gz')]
        targets = [x[:-3] for x in zip_files]

        for idx, zip_file in enumerate(zip_files):
            if not os.path.isfile(targets[idx]):
                print(f"Unzipping {zip_file} to {targets[idx]}")
                with gzip.open(zip_file, 'rb') as f_in:
                    with open(targets[idx], 'wb') as f_out:
                        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)

        from mnist import MNIST

        mndata = MNIST(mnist_dir)
        images, labels = mndata.load_training()
        images = np.array(images)
        labels = np.array(labels)

        idx_dict = {}
        for i in range(10):
            idx_dict[i] = np.where(labels == i)[0]

        # save data for future use
        print(f"Saving images to {mnist_images_fn_loc}...", end="")
        np.save(mnist_images_fn_loc[:-4], images)
        print("DONE")
        print(f"Saving idx dict to {mnist_idx_dict_fn_loc}...", end="")
        with open(mnist_idx_dict_fn_loc, 'wb') as handle:
            pickle.dump(idx_dict, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        print("DONE")

    return images, idx_dict


def create_digit_sequence(n_arr, width, margin_min, margin_max, images, id_dict):
    if margin_max < margin_min:
        return "Maximum margin must be larger or equal to minimum margin"

    image_size = 28
    res = np.zeros((image_size, width, 3))

    extra_margin = width - (len(n_arr) - 1) * margin_min - len(n_arr) * image_size

    if extra_margin < 0:
        return "Current given minimum margin would result in exceeded width"

    start_idx = 0

    for x in n_arr:
        img = images[np.random.choice(id_dict[int(x)])].reshape((28, 28, 1))
        res[:, start_idx:start_idx+28, :] = img
        start_idx += 28
        additional_margin = np.random.randint(0, margin_max - margin_min)
        additional_margin = np.min((extra_margin, additional_margin))
        extra_margin -= additional_margin
        start_idx += additional_margin

    return res


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Generate images from MNIST images for OCR training purposes.')
    parser.add_argument('-w', '--width', default='200',
                        help='Width of the resulting image')
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--minmargin', default='0',
                        help='Minimum margin between MNIST characters')
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--maxmargin', default='100',
                        help='Maximum margin between MNIST characters')
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--strlen', default='5',
                        help='number of characters per string')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--numberstring',
                        help='string of numbers ')
    parser.add_argument('-n', '--genn', default='10',
                        help='number of images to generate')
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--outputdir', default='./images',
                        help='output directory for generated images')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # parse args to int if necessary
    mnist_string = args.numberstring
    min_margin = int(args.minmargin)
    max_margin = int(args.maxmargin)
    width = int(args.width)
    n = int(args.genn)
    str_len = int(args.strlen)
    char_string = args.numberstring

    # load images and idx data
    images, id_dict = load_data_and_dict()

    # create output dir if not exist
    out_dir = args.outputdir
    os.makedirs(out_dir, exist_ok=True)

    # main program loop
    for i in range(n):

        # generate a new string per loop if one wasn't provided
        if char_string is None:
            gen_arr = np.random.randint(0, 9, str_len)
        else:
            gen_arr = [int(x) for x in char_string]

        # run the generator
        mnist_ocr_image = create_digit_sequence(gen_arr, width, min_margin, max_margin, images, id_dict)
        np.save(os.path.join(out_dir, "mnist_ocr_image_{:0>6}".format(i)), mnist_ocr_image)

    print(f"Saved {n} images in {out_dir}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general feedback, the script looks quite good. I will nevertheless share a few of my thoughts with you.

## shebang

Since you are using Python 3, the initial shebang should be `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. Otherwise [it will depend on the system which interpreter is used](https://askubuntu.com/a/817262) to execute the script once the file is marked as executable.

## Documentation

Only `load_data_and_dict()` is documented using a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). The rest of the code is not. It might be a good idea to document the scripts behavior (e.g. directories/files expected/generated by the code) on a module level. To quote PEP 257:

> The docstring of a script (a stand-alone program) should be usable as
>   its "usage" message, printed when the script is invoked with incorrect
>   or missing arguments (or perhaps with a "-h" option, for "help"). Such
>   a docstring should document the script's function and command line
>   syntax, environment variables, and files. Usage messages can be fairly
>   elaborate (several screens full) and should be sufficient for a new
>   user to use the command properly, as well as a complete quick
>   reference to all options and arguments for the sophisticated user.

Since you are working in the scientific Python stack (numpy, ...), it might also be worth to have a look at [numpydoc](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html), the style used for the numpy/scipy/... documentation. It's quite expressive and ready to be used to automatically generate documentation using tools like [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/).

## Error reporting

Returning strings to report errors is not a particularly robust idea. Instead consider raising and catching [exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions) to signal something went wrong. In your case, a [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) seems like an appropriate choice. E.g.

```
raise ValueError("Maximum margin must be larger or equal to minimum margin")
```

Also, `extra_margin` should be checked before creating the `res` image, since it's a useless memory allocation in case the `extra_margin` check won't pass.

## Magic values

Sometimes `28` is used as "magic value", instead of referring to what is defined as `image_size`. Using `image_size` everywhere would be clearer and more consistent.

## Randomness

Maybe you should think about including a possibility to [manually select the seed value for the RNG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21494630/5682996). This will allow you to create reproducible, pseudo-random datasets.

## Command-line interface

`argparse` supports the [`type` keyword argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type), which would allow you to rewrite, e.g.

```
parser.add_argument('-i', '--minmargin', default='0',
                    help='Minimum margin between MNIST characters')
parser.add_argument('-a', '--maxmargin', default='100',
                    help='Maximum margin between MNIST characters')
...
min_margin = int(args.minmargin)
max_margin = int(args.maxmargin)
```

as

```
parser.add_argument('-i', '--minmargin', default='0',
                    help='Minimum margin between MNIST characters', type=int)
parser.add_argument('-a', '--maxmargin', default='100',
                    help='Maximum margin between MNIST characters', type=int)
...
min_margin = args.minmargin   # maybe these even become unnecessary 
max_margin = args.maxmargin
```